# Reference request: an analytical proof the Hilbert space filling curve is nowhere differentiable

Tags: calculus, reference-request, plane-curves

I am studying space filling curves and I am using the Hans Sagan book.

I am trying to understand the nowhere differentiability of the Hilbert curve presented in this book but it does not seem to make much sense to me.

So does anyone have an analytical proof that the Hilbert curve is nowhere differentiable?

The Hilbert curve is defined as the mapping $f_h: I \to \mathcal{Q}$ where I in the unit interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ is the unit square.

$$f_h=(0_4.q_1q_2q_3...)=\sum^\infty_{j=1} (1/2^j)(-1)^{e_{0j}} sgn(q_j)\left(\begin{array}{cc} (1-d_j)g_j-1 \\ 1-d_jq_j \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: If you could define Hilbert curve exactly as it is defined in the book, that would be very helpful in the proof attempt.

Comment: @xyzzyz I have added it in. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised there's a simple formula like that that works for every $t$. If a given $t$ has two different quaternary representations does the formula give the same answer for both representations? (If not we have to choose one, and you left out the statement of which one we use.)

Anyway, it's clear that $f$ is nowhere-differentiable if you look at it right. Fix $t\in[0,1)$. For every $n$ there exists $j$ with $$t\in I_n=[j4^{-n},(j+1)4^{-n}].$$ If $n$ is large enough then $$I_n'=[(j+1)4^{-n},(j+2)4^{-n}]\subset[0,1].$$Now $I_n$ is mapped onto a square $Q_n$ of side length $2^{-n}$, and $I_n'$ is mapped onto a similar square $Q_n'$. Since $Q_n$ and $Q_n'$ are disjoint except for sharing an edge, if $s_n\in I_n'$ is chosen to maximize $|f(t)-f(s_n)|$ then $$|f(t)-f(s_n)|>2^{-n}.$$But $|t-s_n|\le4^{-n+1}$. So $s_n\to t$ but $$\frac{|f(t)-f(s_n)|}{|t-s_n|}\to\infty,$$hence $f$ is not differentiable at $t$.

Comment: Do you have an analytical proof? I should have made it clearer in the question

Comment: @Aljabra If you mean you want a proof based on that series then (i) I can't imagine why you'd prefer that, (ii) you should probably _answer_ the question I asked about it, (iii) you might consider explaining what the notation means: $g_j$, $d_j$, $e_{0j}$ and $sgn(q_j)$ are all undefined so far.